# Upload image with http.post and registration form in Flutter?

Tags: http, post, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

so i want to upload a File (image) to a server with a bunch of other variable (Strings)

String firstname , lastname , birthDay, phone , adresse ; File image;

```
return http.post(
  uri,
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    "Authorization": "Bearer $token",
  },
  body: body,
  encoding: encoding,
);

Future<http.Response> postRegisteration() async {
    return await api.httpPost('fotApp/master', body: {
        'firstname': 'lorem',
        'lastname': 'lorem',
        'birthDay': 'lorem',
        'adresse': 'lorem',
        'phone': 'lorem',
        'image': 'lorem'
      }).then((reponse) {
        var data = jsonDecode(reponse.body);
        print(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

In fileList, you should add any file you like to upload

```
    List<MultipartFile> fileList = List();
    fileList.add(MultipartFile.fromBytes(
        'documents', await filePath.readAsBytes(),
        filename: fileName));
```

For other part parameters use params map

```
    Map<String, String> params = {
      "first_name": widget.mUserDetailsInputmodel.firstName,
      "last_name": widget.mUserDetailsInputmodel.lastName,
      "email": widget.mUserDetailsInputmodel.emailAddress,
    };
```

Then send request somthing like this

```
  Future<String> multipartRequest({var url, var partParams, var files}) async {
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      "X-API-KEY": X_API_KEY,
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "User-Auth-Token": authToken };
    var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse(url));
    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    if (partParams != null) request.fields.addAll(partParams);// add part params if not null
    if (files != null) request.files.addAll(files);// add files if not null

    var response = await request.send();
    var responseData = await response.stream.toBytes();
    var responseString = String.fromCharCodes(responseData);
    print("responseBody " + responseString);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) return responseString;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro , i will test the solution tomorrow in work and see if it's correct , but just looking at it i can tell that it should work