# How to upload image to server API with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter development. My problem is that I try to upload the image but I keep getting failed request.

This piece of code is where I connect it with a server API which will receive the image file from Flutter. String attachment which consist of the image path that is passed from createIncident function located at another page.

```
Future<IncidentCreateResponse> createIncident( String requesterName, String requesterEmail, 
                                              String requesterMobile, String attachment, String title,
                                              String tags, String body, String teamId,
                                              String address )  async {
    IncidentCreateResponse incidentCreateResponse;
    var url = GlobalConfig.API_BASE_HANDESK + GlobalConfig.API_INCIDENT_CREATE_TICKETS;
    var token = Auth().loginSession.accessToken;
    var postBody = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    postBody["requester_name"] = requesterName;
    postBody["requester_email"] = requesterEmail;
    postBody["requester_mobile_no"] = requesterMobile;
    postBody["attachment"] = attachment;
    postBody["title"] = title;
    postBody["tags"] = tags;
    postBody["body"] = body;
    postBody["teamId"] = teamId;
    postBody["address"] = address;

    // Await the http get response, then decode the json-formatted responce.
    var response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: postBody,
        headers: {
          'X-APP-ID': GlobalConfig.APP_ID,
          "Accept": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
          // "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token',
          'token': GlobalConfig.API_INCIDENT_REPORT_TOKEN  
        }
      );
    if ((response.statusCode == 200) || (response.statusCode == 201)) {
      print(response.body);
      var data = json.decode(response.body);

      incidentCreateResponse = IncidentCreateResponse.fromJson(data['data']);
    } else {
      print("createIncident failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.");

      incidentCreateResponse = null;
    }

    return incidentCreateResponse;
  }
```

This is the code snippet where I get the image path from the selected image from the gallery

```
Future getImageFromGallery(BuildContext context) async {
    var picture = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState((){
      _imageFile = picture;
      attachment = basename(_imageFile.path);
    });
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
```

This is the code where I passed the attachment string to the HTTP Response

```
this.incidentService.createIncident(
     Auth().loginSession.name, 
     Auth().loginSession.email, 
     Auth().loginSession.mobile_no, 
     this.attachment,
     this._titleController.text, 
     this._tags, 
     this._contentController.text, 
     this._teamId,
     this._addressController.text
).then((IncidentCreateResponse res) {
     if (res != null) {
        print('Ticket Id: ' + res.id);
        // Navigator.pop(context);
        this._successSubmittionDialog(context);
     } else {
        this._errorSubmittionDialog(context);
     }
}
```

Comment: Check my answer here, This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/58800596/5734205

Comment: Thank you so much. I will test the solution you provided. I think its not a duplication as what his requirement and mine is kinda different.

Comment: Okay, you can upload single and multiple images through my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload image using multipart or base64 Encode.

For uploading image using multipart Visit the [Official documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html)

For uploading image using base64 Encode you can checkout the [Tutorial Here](https://www.coderzheaven.com/2019/04/30/upload-image-in-flutter-using-php/)

I suggest using multipart image upload as it is even reliable when your image or files are larger in size.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this could help you,

create a function to upload your image after picking or clicking an image like,

```
Future<ResponseModel> uploadPhoto(
  String _token,
  File _image,
  String _path,
) async {
  Dio dio = new Dio();
  FormData _formdata = new FormData();
  _formdata.add("photo", new UploadFileInfo(_image, _path));
  final response = await dio.post(
    baseUrl + '/image/upload',
    data: _formdata,
    options: Options(
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        authTokenHeader: _token,
      },
      responseType: ResponseType.json,
    ),
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 500) {
    return ResponseModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.toString()));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to upload!');
  }
}
```

then you can use use uploadImage,

```
uploadImage(_token, _image,_image.uri.toFilePath()).then((ResponseModel response) {
   //do something with the response
});
```

I have used Dio for the task, you can find more detail about dio [here](https://pub.dev/packages/dio#-readme-tab-)

Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  dio: ^3.0.5
```

Then import it in your Dart code, you can use:

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
```

Answer (score 0):

To upload image using multipart API use this code ie

Add this library `dio` in your project in `pubspec.yaml` file

```
dio: ^3.0.5
```

and import this in your class

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
```

Declare this variable in your class like `State<CustomClass>`

```
static var uri = "BASE_URL_HERE";
  static BaseOptions options = BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: uri,
      responseType: ResponseType.plain,
      connectTimeout: 30000,
      receiveTimeout: 30000,
      validateStatus: (code) {
        if (code >= 200) {
          return true;
        }
      });
  static Dio dio = Dio(options);
```

then use this method to upload file

```
Future<dynamic> _uploadFile() async {
    try {
      Options options = Options(
          //contentType: ContentType.parse('application/json'), // only for json type api
          );

      var directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory(); // directory path
      final path = await directory.path; // path of the directory
      Response response = await dio.post('/update_profile',
          data: FormData.from({
            "param_key": "value",
            "param2_key": "value",
            "param3_key": "value",
            "profile_pic_param_key": UploadFileInfo(File("$path/pic.jpg"), "pic.jpg"),

          }),
          options: options);
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
      if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
        var responseJson = json.decode(response.data);
        return responseJson;
      } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
        print(' response code 401');
        throw Exception("Incorrect Email/Password");
      } else
        throw Exception('Authentication Error');
    } on DioError catch (exception) {
      if (exception == null ||
          exception.toString().contains('SocketException')) {
        throw Exception("Network Error");
      } else if (exception.type == DioErrorType.RECEIVE_TIMEOUT ||
          exception.type == DioErrorType.CONNECT_TIMEOUT) {
        throw Exception(
            "Could'nt connect, please ensure you have a stable network.");
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I am getting error at 'UploadFileInfo'. Am I missing something?